# updmap-sys and others not found [MacOs]

Tags: mac, texlive-2019

Trying to update my distribution via Tex Live Manager (MacOs 10.15.3) the updater seems to have trouble to find neccessary programs:

```
2020-01-31 08:22:53 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[1522] tlmgr: fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luahbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --all failed (status -1), output:
```

Trying

```
which  updmap-sys
```

gives

```
updmap-sys not found
```

Similar for `fmtutils-sys`.  What's going wrong here?

Is it strange that `updmap-sys` is a link at

```
/usr/local/TeXLive/2019/bin/x86_64-darwin
```

which points to

```
/usr/local/TeXLive/2019/bin/x86_64-darwin/updmap-sys
```

that is, to itself?

EDIT: When I demand to show the original of updmap-sys I'm prompted with the message that the original couldn't be found; thanks to @AlainMatthes. Strange enough,

```
michaelhoppe@KINO ~ % ls /usr/local/TeXLive/2019/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive
```

gives not more than

```
 NEWS           lua         tl-errmess.vbs      tlmgrgui.pl  uninstq.vbs
README          mktexlsr        tlmgr.pl        uninstall-win32.pl
```

I'm more than baffled.

EDIT^2:  Using Time Machine I noticed that those scripts passed by after the recent update to 10.15.3. I've restored the directory from two days ago. Now updmap is found, BUT has problems:

```
2020-01-31 10:57:51 +0000 Notice -[TLMMainWindowController _runUpdmap][3505]    updmap had problems:

Use of uninitialized value $fn in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/local/TeXLive/2019/bin/x86_64-darwin/updmap line 2157.
```

[...]

```
updmap [ERROR]: The following map file(s) couldn't be found:

updmap [ERROR]:     dvips35.map (in builtin)

updmap [ERROR]:     pdftex35.map (in builtin)

updmap [ERROR]:     ps2pk35.map (in builtin)
```

Comment: Just to check, what does `which pdflatex` return? Might be that the special path used on the mac dropped out of your search path on the mac

Comment: pdflatex lives in /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex according to which.

Comment: Ahh, just remembered, `updmap-sys` has been gone for a while. It confused too many users, instead use `updmap --sys ...` it was changed in 2017

Comment: Well, but updmap itself isn't found: zsh: command not found: updmap ...

Comment: Then you probably have a very strange setup, I have it in `/opt/texlive/current/bin/x86_64-linux/updmap` on my linux box. BTW: where does `/Library/TeX/texbin` point to? It is normally a softlink, and I'm wondering if you have several latex installations and that texbin currently points to an old one.

Comment: On my mac : `/Library/TeX/texbin/updmap-sys` and `texbin` is an alias  for `/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-darwin` and then a new alias `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/updmap-sys.sh`

Comment: I have both on my system as well. Perhaps you should reinstall MecTeX 2019 just in case the mac update did something it should not, would not be the first time.

Comment: I presume that MacOs isn't the culprit, but tlmgr instead: after executing an update of tlmgr, that script-directory was missing files again.

Comment: @daleif: updmap-sys certainly still exists in TeX Live 2019. Also, with a MacTeX installed TeX Live there is a data structure to allow for simple change of the active TeX distribution. The binaries are indirectly pointed to by /Library/TeX/texbin.

Comment: @HerbSchulz They pointed, but the script didn't exist in /usr/local/TeXLive/2019/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive , see my question.  I reinstalled /usr/local/TeXLive/2019 from Time Machine, now the system works.  I have no idea why those scripts vanished.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: /Library/TeX/texbin points to the TeX binaries, not the root of the distribution. The root of the active distribution is at /Library/TeX/Root so the scripts folder can be reached by /Library/TeX/Root/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive. Try doing `ls -alf /Library/TeX/Root/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive` to see if the updmap-sys script is there and `ls -alf /Library/TeX/texbin/updmap*` to see if the symlinks are present in the binary folder.

Comment: You might try to re-install tlmgr using TeX Live Utility. It may be that the database is messed up.